# Terminal Software to add Watermarks to Videos?

Tags: linux, bash, python

I have a bunch of videos, 12,000+ a month. I would like to add a watermark to all of them, like a logo with our website.

Is there any software I can use on the Terminal to do this? Ideally I'd like to create a bash, or python, script to go through the videos and watermark them.

I'm using Debian Jessie if it's of any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found `ffmpeg` which can be used to watermark videos with a transparent PNG. This is perfect.